# Stymied by PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Having a problem with the following preg_replace:

```
$subject = '<div class="main"> <div class="block_bc"> <a href="index.php?x_param=11" class="BC-1"> Gallery</a> / <a href="path/Title_Item/?x_param=17" class="BC-2"> Title Item</a> / <span class="BC-3"> Bridge</span> </div> </div>';
$regex = '/(<div\sclass=\"block_bc\"[^>]*>)([^<\/div>]*>)(<\/div>)/is';   
$replacement = '<div class="block_bc"></div>';
preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $subject);
```

Basically, I want to end up with `<div class="main"> <div class="block_bc"></div> </div>` but it is not getting selected.

Can anyone please point me to the "obvious" error?

Comment: Stop parsing html with regex, please.

Comment: Not particularly helpful since you did not add the the alternative solution to your answer. Can you do so please?

Comment: [Here's the alternative and much reliable thing for parsing html](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: Thanks. I'll bear it in mind for some other time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to use character classes (`[]`) wrong. The `[^<\/div>]*` part means that number of characters except one of the following: `<`,`/`,`d`,`i`,`v`,`>`. This probably not what you meant.

What you could use is [non-greedy repeat](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy):

```
$regex = '/(<div\s*class=\"block_bc\"[^>]*>)(.+?)(<\/div>)/is';
```

Also, getting things out from html with regexp can be extremely brittle, try using the DOM for this with xpath. It's more verbose but also more resilient for badly formatted input:

```
$subject = '<div class="main"> <div class="block_bc"> <a href="index.php?x_param=11" class="BC-1"> Gallery</a> / <a href="path/Title_Item/?x_param=17" class="BC-2"> Title Item</a> / <span class="BC-3"> Bridge</span> </div> </div>';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // supress warnings
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($subject);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
// get the <div class="main"> node for exporting
$main_node  = $xpath->query('//div[@class="main"]');
// select the block_bc classed div's childs, and the textnodes under it
$childNodes = $xpath->query('//div[@class="block_bc"]/* | //div[@class="block_bc"]/text()'); 
foreach ($childNodes as $c) {
    $c->parentNode->removeChild($c); // clear them all
}

// export the part of the document under the <div class="main">
print $doc->saveHTML($main_node->item(0)); 
// update:
// if you want the full document in html you can simply omit the parameter, with this you can get rid of the $main_node = ... line too
print $doc->saveHTML(); // this will print from doctype to </html>
```

Comment: Close ... but the `(.+?)`, and other similar ones given, falls down when it encounters a space. I know `.` is supposed to mean every character but it seems to be every charater except "space" on my server.

Comment: That certainly sounds strange. I guess this is not the full input (newlines or more content removed), Try using the `m` modifier too for multiline matches. I'm not sure about your original input, but simple newlines should be covered by the `s` already.

Comment: Also you can write it like `((?:.|\s)+?)` to explicitly tell that spaces should be consumed too, but i can't reproduce your `.` not-matching-space results.

Comment: The update is looking good but can you kindly amend so that when it prints, it prints the whole HTML page. I tried to change `$subject` to the full page but got lost along the way. (talking about the "DOM" update that is.

Comment: PS. You are a star! The `((?:.|\s)+?)` did the trick! Still curious about the DOM one if you don't mind educating me a bit. I'll accept the answer all the same

Comment: Nevermind, I'll learn the DOM thing later. The regex fix works good for now. Thanks again!

Comment: By simply using the [saveHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) without parameter should export the full document (added to the example code too)

Answer (score 0):

Pattern

```
~<div\sclass="block_bc"[^>]*>.*</div>~isU
```

will work until you add some divs inside "block_bc".

Answer (score 0):

[^</div>] just creates a character class without '<', '/', 'd', 'i', 'v', and '>'. It is not doing what you think it would. Replacing the middle part with a non-greedy any match should do the trick:

```
'/(<div\sclass=\"block_bc\"[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/div>)/is'
```